# Has anyone used SmartThreadPool of Ami Bar and can share his/her experience with it?

Tags: .net, multithreading, threadpool

I am looking into alternative ThreadPool implementations and have found the [SmartThreadPool](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/threads/smartthreadpool.aspx) implementation by Ami Bar. It looks very interesting, so my question is whether anyone has actually used it and if so - please share the experience.

Thanks.

**P.S.**

Our thread usage matches the one described as optimal by Ami Bar - many threads doing I/O for long period of time.

BTW, if there are other interesting ThreadPool implementations, I am interested to hear about them as well. (I am also aware of the Stephen Toub's implementation).

Answer (score 2):

I used it in an ASP.NET `IHttpAsyncHandler` for download bandwidth throttling and just worked fine.